# How to import a library in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to flutter and I want to use this library in my project, but I am getting the following error. Please, any suggestions?

https://pub.dev/packages/bls_signatures_ffi

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bls_signatures_ffi:generateJsonModelDebug'.
> exception while building Json $C:\Users\razia\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\bls_signatures_ffi-0.1.0\android\.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\_deps\bls-src\.git\objects\pack\pack-a40d22d0092127754e8a2691ff349c3bc271c942.idx
```

local.properties file

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\razia\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C\:\\Program Files\\flutter\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

Comment: Do `flutter run` with --verbose flag and see more about the error at "Execution failed ...". From there we can know exactly what is wrong. Hope your Flutter is working well and you have been able to run it on another project.

Answer (score 0):

```
Depend on it
    1.**Open the pubspec.yaml file located inside the app folder, and add css_colors: under dependencies.
Install it**
    2.**From the terminal: Run flutter pub get.
    OR
    From Android Studio/IntelliJ: Click Packages get in the action ribbon at the top of pubspec.yaml.
    From VS Code: Click Get Packages located in right side of the action ribbon at the top of pubspec.yaml.**
3.**Import it
    Add a corresponding import statement in the Dart code.
Stop and restart the app, if necessary
    If the package brings platform-specific code (Kotlin/Java for Android, Swift/Objective-C for iOS), that code must be built into your app. Hot reload and hot restart only update the Dart code, so a full restart of the app might be required to avoid errors like MissingPluginException when using the package.**
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).